ASP.NET Core: "The view 'Index' was not found" on Mac with Visual Studio 2022 and Apple M1 Pro
I'm developing an ASP.NET Core application on a MacBook Pro with an Apple M1 Pro processor, using Visual Studio 2022 version 17.6.14 (build 413).
When I launch my project with the command:
dotnet watch run

I encounter the following error:
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.ViewEngineResult.EnsureSuccessful(IEnumerable<string> originalLocations)


My question is:
Why can't the application find the 'Index.cshtml' view even though it exists in the correct location?

Hi @rafik, how is your backend code?
